# Программа не работает при вводе русской а

Tags: c++

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void aaaaaaa(string S) {
    int max = 0;
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < S.length() - 1; i++) {
        while (S[i] == 'a')
        {
            k++;
            i++;
            if (k > max) {
                max = k;
            }
        }
        k = 0;

    }
    cout << "самое большое количество букв а идущих подряд = " << max << endl;
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    string S;
    cout << "Введите строку " << endl;
    getline(cin, S);
    aaaaaaa(S);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: У вас система windows? Тогда нужен setlocale

Comment: В main он присутствует

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? В цикле `while (S[i] == 'a' || S[i] == 'а')` два одинаковых условия и нет проверки на выход за пределы строки.

Comment: При вводе русских а  всегда пишет, что max  = 1

Comment: cin не поддерживает ввод юникода, стоит использовать wchar и wscanf и wprintf

Comment: Если это VS, то вместо `setlocale` используйте `SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);     SetConsoleCP(1251);`, кроме того, убедитесь, что `'a'` русская.